# How to seperate one column into two columns in R?

Tags: r

I have one column as mentioned below and I want to split into two columns date and time. How can I do that ?

```
X$Datime
11/7/2016 11:51
11/7/2016 17:57
12/7/2016 9:17
12/7/2016 21:08
13-07-2016 08:33:16
13-07-2016 21:57:28
14-07-2016 06:15:32
15-07-2016 05:11:52
15-07-2016 17:57:27
11/7/2016 6:46
12/7/2016 5:08
12/7/2016 12:30
13-07-2016 04:49:20
```

Comment: `strsplit(X$Datime, " ")`?

Comment: `tidyr::separate` can be an option.

Comment: You can convert the variable into a `POSIX` object (e.g. `as.POSIXlt`) and then extract relevant parts using `strptime`.

Comment: Note that base R doesn't have a data type for just "time" so it's usually better to keep them together and just parse the value as a date-time value. You can use a library like `lubridate` to extract whatever part of the date-time off that you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `strsplit`.

```
Y <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(X$Datime, " "))
Y <- as.data.frame(Y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(Y) <- c("Date", "time")
```

Note that the column `Datime` must be of class `character` for the above code to work. Many times character vectors are of class `factor`, when they are a data.frame column. If it is the case with your data, use instead

```
strsplit(as.character(X$Datime), " ")
```

**Data.**

```
Datime <- scan(what = character(), text = "
11/7/2016 11:51
11/7/2016 17:57
12/7/2016 9:17
12/7/2016 21:08
13-07-2016 08:33:16
13-07-2016 21:57:28
14-07-2016 06:15:32
15-07-2016 05:11:52
15-07-2016 17:57:27
11/7/2016 6:46
12/7/2016 5:08
12/7/2016 12:30
13-07-2016 04:49:20
", sep = "\n")

X <- data.frame(Datime, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```